# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value

Tags: json, spring, postman

I want to insert multiple data in postman but, I get this eror

"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.test.rest.api.dtos.AnggotaDTO` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.test.rest.api.dtos.AnggotaDTO` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",

How i can resolve this eror ?

This is my request body, post in postman

```
[
  {
      anggotaNama: "AAA",
      anggotaUsia: 16
  },
  {
      anggotaNama: "BBB",
      anggotaUsia: 17
  },
  {
      anggotaNama: "CCC",
      anggotaUsia: 18
  } 
]
```

This is my dtos.AnggotaDTO

```
package com.test.rest.api.dtos;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor

public class AnggotaDTO {

  private long anggotaId;

  private String anggotaNama;

  private int anggotaUsia;

}
```

This my controller

```
package com.test.rest.api.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.rest.api.dtos.AnggotaDTO;
import com.test.rest.api.models.Anggota;
import com.test.rest.api.repositories.AnggotaRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")

public class AnggotaController {

@Autowired
private AnggotaRepository anggotaRepository;

ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();


private Anggota convertAnggotaToEntity (AnggotaDTO anggotaDto) {
    return modelMapper.map(anggotaDto, Anggota.class);
}

private AnggotaDTO convertAnggotaToDTO (Anggota anggota) {
    return modelMapper.map(anggota, AnggotaDTO.class);
}

//  API CREATE Anggota
@PostMapping("/anggota/create")
public Map<String, Object> createAnggota(@RequestBody AnggotaDTO anggotaDTO) {
    Map<String, Object> mapResult = new HashMap<>();
    
    Anggota anggota = convertAnggotaToEntity(anggotaDTO);
    anggota.setAnggotaNama(anggotaDTO.getAnggotaNama());
    anggota.setAnggotaUsia(anggotaDTO.getAnggotaUsia());
    
    mapResult.put("message", "Craete Success");
    mapResult.put("data", anggotaRepository.save(anggota));
    
    return mapResult;
}
//  API READ Anggota 
@GetMapping("/anggota/get/findall")
public Map<String, Object> getAllAnggota () {
    Map<String, Object> mapResult = new HashMap<>();
    List<AnggotaDTO> listAnggotaDto = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Anggota anggota : anggotaRepository.findAll()) {
        AnggotaDTO anggotaDto = convertAnggotaToDTO(anggota);
        listAnggotaDto.add(anggotaDto);
    }
    
    String message;
    if (listAnggotaDto.isEmpty()) {
        message = "Data is empty";
    }
    else {
        message = "Show all data";
    }
    
    mapResult.put("message" , message);
    mapResult.put("data", listAnggotaDto);
    mapResult.put("total", listAnggotaDto.size());
    
    return mapResult;
}
//  API UPDATE Anggota
@PutMapping("/anggota/update")
public Map<String, Object> updateAnggota (@RequestParam(value="anggotaId") long anggotaId, @RequestBody AnggotaDTO anggotaDto) {
    Map<String, Object> mapResult = new HashMap<>();
    
    Anggota anggota = anggotaRepository.findById(anggotaId).orElse(null);
    
    anggota.setAnggotaNama(anggotaDto.getAnggotaNama());
    anggota.setAnggotaUsia(anggotaDto.getAnggotaUsia());
    
    mapResult.put("message", "Update success");
    mapResult.put("data", anggotaRepository.save(anggota));
    
    return mapResult;
    }
//  API Delete Employee
@DeleteMapping("/anggota/delete/{anggotaId}")
public Map<String, Object> deleteAnggota (@PathVariable(value="anggotaId") long anggotaId) {
    Map<String, Object> mapResult = new HashMap<>();
    
    Anggota anggota = anggotaRepository.findById(anggotaId).orElse(null);
    anggotaRepository.delete(anggota);
    
    mapResult.put("message", "Delete Success");
    
    return mapResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Spring, but I see the mismatch here. You push an array of `AnggotaDTO` but you mapping with single  `AnggotaDTO`. I think `@RequestBody AnggotaDTO` --> `@RequestBody List<AnggotaDTO>`, again I'm not sure about Spring.